OpenMP on for loop takes much more time than serial code
I tried parallelizing a code snippet with OpenMP, it turns out that engaging OpenMP takes 25X time for the program to finish. Is there anything wrong? How can I optimize it?
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        unsigned long long black_square = 1, digit_square = 13;
        //auto n = ((black_square)<<11) * static_cast<unsigned long long>(pow(digit_square,10));
        auto n = static_cast<unsigned long long>(1e9);
        srand(0);
        int tmp = 0;
        std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
        std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);

        auto tStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
//#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:tmp)
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:tmp) num_threads(8)
        for (unsigned long long i=0; i<n; i++) tmp = (tmp+(5==rand()%6))%static_cast<int>(1e9);
        //for (unsigned long long i=0; i<n; i++) tmp = (tmp+(5==distrib(gen)))%static_cast<int>(1e9);
        tmp%=static_cast<int>(1e9);
        auto tEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        cout << tmp << " obtained after " << n << " iterations in " << (tEnd-tStart).count()/1e9 << "s." << endl;
        return 0;
}

The code is compiled by g++ -o a.out -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp tmp.cpp where g++ has version 8.5.0 20210514. The OS is RHEL8.9 and there are 20 Intel Xeon CPUs at 2.593GHz.
The serial code on average runs in 7.4s while the parallel code on average runs in 180s. Options -O3, -O2, -O1 have similar results. Random generator mt19937 could reduce the performance gap significantly, but the parallel code is still much slower than the serial version. Increasing or decreasing n leads to similar results as well.

Update with resutls.
I tried both the array approach and the firstprivate approach as in the answers/comments.They have comparable results and both achieve true parallelism. Not test whether the random sequences from each thread in the firstprivate approach are the same yet.
void array_approach(unsigned long long n, const int nThreads) {
        int tmp = 0;
        std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
        vector<std::mt19937> rngs;
        for (int i=0; i<nThreads*64; i++) rngs.push_back(std::mt19937(rd())); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);
        auto tStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:tmp) num_threads(nThreads)
        for (unsigned long long i=0; i<n; i++) tmp = (tmp+(5==distrib(rngs[omp_get_thread_num()*64])))%static_cast<int>(1e9);
        tmp%=static_cast<int>(1e9);
        auto tEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << tmp << " obtained after " << n << " iterations in " << (tEnd-tStart).count()/1e9 << "s." << endl;
}

void private_approach(unsigned long long n, const int nThreads) {
        int tmp = 0;
        std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
        std::mt19937 rng(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);
        auto tStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:tmp) firstprivate(rng) num_threads(nThreads)
        for (unsigned long long i=0; i<n; i++) tmp = (tmp+(5==distrib(rng)))%static_cast<int>(1e9);
        tmp%=static_cast<int>(1e9);
        auto tEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << tmp << " obtained after " << n << " iterations in " << (tEnd-tStart).count()/1e9 << "s." << endl;
}


Looks like tmp is being accessed by multiple threads using OpenMP, since it is a single variable the overhead introduced by OpenMP in creating and managing multiple threads all accessing tmp would lead to higher processing time.

Actions in (tmp+(5==rand()%6))%static_cast<int>(1e9); are extremely small in cost compared to shared access overhead while there is asingle shared object. That would ensure that there is no parallel execution, more like "lock step" execution.

Are you summing coin tosses 1 with p=1/6, 0 with 1-p? That has asymptotically normal distribution {np,sqrt(np*(1-p)}. If you need to do it in parallel, n is large, then the normal distribution should yield very close result. I think modulo operation can be done only at the very end together with rounding to nearest integer.

@Chaitanya There is reduction(+:tmp) in the code. Isn't it that a local copy of tmp is created for each thread? I'm new to OpenMP.

@Quimby Yes it's basicaly a coin with 1/6 probability. The modulo operation is to prevent overflow when n is very huge. Is there any way that each thread can use their own local variable for modulo?

@cat I would assume that tmp is handled by OpenMP, the issue is all other state - rand, distrib, gen  - access to these variables has to be serialized. I think the best way would be for each thread to have its own RNG but I do not know how to do that in OpenMP, sorry.

rand() keeps an internal state. For rand to be thread safe, it needs to run serially, so probably has mutex locks in place somewhere.. You could try using instead a PRNG you can execute in parallel with each thread having its own state. If you need high levels of evenness though, it might not be trivial. I think rand just uses a linear congruence anyway, so you can get something just as good as rand without too much work.

@cat the overhead of reducing 'tmp' at the end each time might be too high, but as others have stated I think rand() might be the main problem since it is not thread-safe and it updates its internal state each time it is called

Note that high_resolution_clock should not be used here as it is not meant to measure the wall clock time. For example, It is not guaranteed to be monotonic so the timings can be negative. You should use a steady_clock instead, or even better : omp_get_wtime.

The array approach initializes each rng with a different seed. Your firstprivate approach creates a private copy with the same initial seed. You might alternatively try to create the rng inside the parallel region and init the rng with a different seed for each thread.

The rand() function is not required to be thread safe.  So it isn't safe to call it from multiple threads at once, like you're doing
glibc's version of rand() is thread safe, but it does by wrapping the entire function in a mutex.  So only one thread can call rand() at a time.  Since outside of the rand call, you're code does very little, virtually all the execution time will be inside rand().
So the parallel version is not really parallel.  Each thread takes turns to execute one at a time on each call to rand().  So it has no advantage over a single thread.  But it's actually worse, because the threads have to fight over who gets the mutex, wake up and sleep after each call, and move the PRNG state between each CPU core's cache.  So it's much worse than a single threaded.
What you should do is create multiple PRNG instances.  Have an array of the gen object, one for each thread.  Each thread should use its own PRNG.  Make sure each object is far enough apart in memory to not share a cache line so the PRNG state does not need to move between CPU caches.

An array of PRNG is certainly not a so good idea, typically due to false sharing (serializing the execution due to cache line bouncing as you mentioned). Adding so padding between items solve the problem but the space is dependent of the CPU and it is not so great to loose a lot of space (eg. 64-128 byte for a 4-16 byte PRNG state) It is certainly better to use a thread private PRNG by just declaring it in a parallel region. One can also use firstprivate to copy locally the PRNG from a shared array if any so to avoid false sharing, but the former is more efficient (no copy).

I did say to make sure the array spaces the states far enough apart to not share.  Use std::hardware_destructive_interference_size to get how far apart that is.  One does not want to copy a PRNG for each thread.  If they have the same state when they are copied, they will all generate the same PRN sequence!

Yes. Good point for hardware_destructive_interference_size but I wonder if it is 128 on Intel CPU loading 2 cache lines of 64 bytes per fetch (AFAIK it is 64 which is still much better than no padding). For the copy, I did say "copy locally the PRNG from a shared array" so the initial PRNG are different ;) . The shared array is smaller though it still take more space than a simple local initialization that should be preferred (especially on NUMA systems).
